# How do I disable app-specific notification sounds? In system Notification Settings, this particular app has "Sounds" toggled to off

Tags: sound, notification

The app is Discord. Maybe Discord is producing its own sound and circumvents Ubuntu's notification sound controls. In which case, where is the Sound or Volume Mixer app to silence Discord entirely?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pl4kx.png - picture of the settings as they are

Edit: David says it's Discord. So how can Ubuntu silence it? This is the only thing that appears for volume controls:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq0js.png - I only have system or Firefox to mute, nothing for Discord.

Comment: It is in the discord app noting to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: To turn off Discord notification sounds, start by going to User Settings. In User Settings, click Notifications. Scroll down to the Sounds section. There are 18 sounds that you can go through and manually disable.

Answer (score 0):

If you find that an app does not obey system sound rules it may be due to the fact the app has its own rules.

In this case Discord.

To turn off Discord notification sounds, start by going to User Settings. In User Settings, click Notifications. Scroll down to the Sounds section. There are 18 sounds that you can go through and manually disable.